# Numbers on telephone to letters. 2=ABC 3=DEF etc. Using switch case but code isnt giving desired results. How would I return the code as asked below

Tags: matlab

```
for var=1:length(str)
switch str(var)
   case {'A':'C'}
     disp('2')
   case {'D':'F'}
     disp('3')
   case {'G':'I'}
     disp('4')
   case {'J':'L'}
     disp('5')
   case {'M':'O'}
     disp('6')
   case {'P' 'R' 'S'}
     disp('7')
   case {'T':'V'}
     disp('8')
   case {'W':'Y'}
     disp('9')
end
```

I am using this code in trying to make a statement such as ('1-800-TO-WELLS') become '1-800-86-93557', but the output is "str=1-800-TO-WELLS and 7". Any amount of tips and help is very appreciated. If I haven't provided a valid enough question please leave comments so I can improve.

Comment: Yeah I have. It just shows that the switch ends with an end statement

Comment: @mdave16 MATLAB case statments in `switch` blocks don't fall through like in other langauges with `break` reserved exclusively for loops.

Answer (score 2):

For strings, the cases in the `switch` block act like calls to `strcmp`, so `case <caseExpression>` is true if `any(strcmp(<caseExpression>,<switchExpression>))`.

This is important because `{'P' 'R' 'S'}` and `{'P':'S'}` do not generate the same output:

```
>> {'P' 'R' 'S'}
ans = 
    'P'    'R'    'S'
>> {'P':'S'}
ans = 
    'PQRS'
```

The first is a 1-by-3 cell array with individual characters as the elements' contents; the second is a 1-by-1 cell array with a 1-by-4 character array as the element's content. Performing a `strcmp` on the first one will give true if the `<switchExpression>` is a letter in the set while the second will only give a true if `<switchExpression>` is exactly `'PQRS'`:

```
>> strcmp({'P' 'R' 'S'},'S')
ans =
     0     0     1
>> strcmp({'P':'S'},'S')
ans =
     0
>> strcmp({'P':'S'},'P':'S')
ans =
     1
```

So the `7` pops out because its case is the only one that gives true when given a matching character.

---

As a side note, you may consider using the `otherwise` statement to echo non-matching characters:

```
switch str(var)
.
.
.
    otherwise
        disp(str(var));
end
```

Answer (score 1):

[Troy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47047714/52738) gives a very clear answer as to why your code isn't working: `{'A':'C'}` results in a 1-element cell array `{'ABC'}`, but you want to use a 3-element cell array `{'A' 'B' 'C'}` since the way the [`switch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html) compares case expressions will result in a match if one cell element *exactly* matches a given character.

As an alternative to using a `for` loop and `switch` statement, you could also do this using the [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) function and some indexing:

```
% Character/number map and test string:
map = ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUVWXY'; '222333444555666777888999'];
str = '1-800-TO-WELLS';

% Convert test string:
[isInMap, index] = ismember(str, map(1, :));
str(isInMap) = map(2, index(isInMap));
```

And the result:

```
str =

1-800-86-93557
```